# How to limit WPF DataGridTextColum Text max length to 10 characters

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

How can I limit WPF `DataGridTextColumn` Text to max length of 10 characters.

I don't want to use `DatagridTemplateColumn`, because it has memory leak problems.

Also the field is bound to a data entity model.

Comment: what's wrong with accepted solution to your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026252/datagridtemplate-column-with-textbox-not-retaining-the-value-in-the-datagrid-col) and what _memory leak_ are you talking about?

Comment: The value for the field is not getting saved in Entity Data Model. As from Grid to Context binding is not happening... Also I read that DatagridtemplateColumn has some memory leak issues...!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't want to use `DatagridTemplateColumn` then you can change [`DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle.aspx) and set `TextBox.MaxLength` there:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SellingPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: How to used TextBlock

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm gravedigging a bit, but I came up with another solution to this that I didn't find anywhere else. It involves the use of a value converter. A bit hacky, yes, but it has the advantage that it doesn't pollute the xaml with many lines, which might be useful, if you want to apply this to many columns.

The following converter does the job. Just add the following reference to `App.xaml` under `Application.Resources`: `<con:StringLengthLimiter x:Key="StringLengthLimiter"/>`, where `con` is the path to the converter in `App.xaml`.

```
public class StringLengthLimiter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value!=null)
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int strLimit = 3;
            try
            {
                string strVal = value.ToString();
                if(strVal.Length > strLimit)
                {
                    return strVal.Substring(0, strLimit);
                }
                else
                {
                    return strVal;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
    }
```

Then just reference the converter in xaml binding like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SellingPrice,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource StringLengthLimiter}}">
```

Comment: after 3 digit then not press extra digit?